# Sharepoint online - Upload and set metadata information

Tags: sharepoint

I need to upload around 10000 files to a Picture Library in Sharepoint Online. These files need to have some extra informantions like date, description and others. I have these info in a CSV file.

How could I upload and set these extra info?
I saw this Codeplex... http://get-spscripts.com/2010/10/bulk-upload-files-with-metadata-into.html but I didnt find any relation to na external csv files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using that CodePlex script would be your best starting point. However, that script is expecting the metadata in XML through the ManifestFilePath. So you would change the [xml] (Get-Content ($ManifestFilePath)) to use Import-Csv instead. You would then also need to change $metadataManifest.Columns.Column to just be $metadataManifest | ForEach-Object.

Lastly, your CSV schema will need to match either what this powershell script is expecting, or you will need to do additional tweaks to the ForEach-Object section of this script to match your CSV.

Comment: Hi Maarten, Codeplex use Get-SPWeb that is note available in SP Online.

Comment: Get-SPOWeb is the SP Online equivalent. I'd do a find/replace and test if all the functions supported meet your needs.